# How to make particular data attribute(data-number) to tel link which matches with regular expression

Tags: jquery

I want to make particular data attribute(data-number) to tel.Ex.

```
<p data-number="(+91) 000-000-00000">(+91) 000-000-00000</p>
<p data-number="(111) 111-1111">(111) 111-1111</p>
<div data-number="(+91) 111-111-11111">(+91) 111-111-11111</div>
<div data-number="(111) 111-1111">(111) 111-1111</div>
```

I want to convert only those numbers which matches with my regular expression to `<a href="tel:"></a>`.I tried like this

```
var n = $("[data-number]").length;
var array = $("[data-number]");
var re = /^\(\+\d{2}\)\s|\+\d{2}-|\d{3,4}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?(\d{4,5})\b$/;
var result;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Tel_Number = array.eq(i).attr('data-number');
    if (Tel_Number.match(re)) {
        alert(Tel_Number);
    }
}
```

I am getting the numbers which are matching with regular expression in alert.The numbers which matches I want to convert them to `<a href="tel:></a>`. I got one solution to convert all data numbers to tel like this:

```
$("p[data-number]").each(function() {

    var $a = $("<a />").attr("href", "tel:" + $(this).data("number"));
    $a.html($(this).html());
    $(this).html($a);
});
```

Please suggest me how to convert the numbers which are matching to `<a href="tel:></a>`

Comment: please see my answer and check if this works well for you or not

Comment: @innomanik - It is working for me..Thanks!! I want to know if the number might within any tag like this `<div> 1122334455 </div>`  or `<p>1122334455 </p>` How to make it as tel link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified some so your code and got this working, see below-

```
var re = /^\(\+\d{2}\)\s|\+\d{2}-|\d{3,4}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?(\d{4,5})\b$/;
$("[data-number]").each(function () {
    var Tel_Number = $(this).attr('data-number');
    if (Tel_Number.match(re)) {
        var $a = $("<a />").attr("href", "tel:" + $(this).data("number"));
        $a.html($(this).html());
        $(this).html($a);
    }
});
```

Working Fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/sh4mkrbg/1/